# How can i forward to a jsp from a servlet that has been called with ajax

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, jsp, servlets

I'm successfuly calling a servlet using ajax, but then in the servlet i can't redirect to a jsp
Here is my code to call the servlet

```
$("#nextButton").on("click", function() {
    var param = JSON.stringify(Polo);
    $.ajax({
        url:"ServletURL",
        type:"POST",
        dataType:'json',
        data: {json:param},
        success: function() {
                console.log('success');
        }
    });
});
```

but in the servlet i can't redirect to a jsp

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    String myJsonData = request.getParameter("json");
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    Polo polo = gson.fromJson(str, Polo.class);
    request.setAttribute("Polo", polo);
    request.getRequestDispatcher("/page2/page2.jsp").forward(request, response);

}

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
 */
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    doGet(request, response);
}
```

but everything is working fine i don't get any error , but the jsp doesn't appear on my browser. am i doing something wrong ?

i already looked for some solutions on stack overflow , but i didn't understand some of the answers so if you can give a clear explanation on the issue and how to solve it i will really appreciate it. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

(In advance, I can't post the comment yet because of low rating points!)

I think that everything works correctly! But you are sending your request asynchronously. So your web browser will not redirect. Please open dev-tools in your browser (F12 in Chrome and most of other modern browsers), navigate to network tab, find your request and take a look at response

I think you will find your JSP contents there.

(btw, I can't upload file, some unknown 'imgur error' appears)

Answer (score 0):

you are calling POST, in which is not programmed to redirect to a jsp, update the ajax parameter `type:"POST"` to `type:"GET"` to get desired result